# getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder") return null

Tags: java, file

I have tried to list jar folder files using

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folderName")` it return `null`

but `getClass().getResourceAsStream("folderName/fileName")` not `null`

**what is the difference?**

it works in eclipse but not in `jar` file

Comment: Apart from the missing leading `/`, can you post a directory structure of your application? Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Folders don't exist in jar files. You can't list folders inside a jar.

Comment: Add listing of contents of jar file to question.

Comment: @bmargulies , there is a solution is to list jar files and filter the specific folder

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the [Class Loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) to locate the file (resource) in `"/folderName"` which is the root (absolute). While `"folderName"` is the current folder (relative to) your class is located in.

Plus:

- `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` is using the System Class Loader. Not the class loader that loaded the parent class.
- Use `Example.class.getResourceAsStream()` and you should be able to access the resources.
- Also if you're obfuscating the JAR you can't use a static path.